# How to perform a Non-Interactive MFA Login to Azure Subscription using Powershell

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

Previously, I was able to login to the azure subscription via powershell using the below code.

```
$azureAccountName ="username"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred
```

Recently, Microsoft introduced MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) and now the above code fails as we now have to verify the login via a code received on the mobile number registered at the time of profile creation.
I do not want the interactive login but the automatic one which my code was earlier able to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: also MFA was introduced literally ages ago. It was there at least back in 2012

Comment: Both answers by Jason Ye and 4c74356b41 are valid. You can't sign in non-interactively to an account which has MFA. Same thing for federated accounts. You probably need to use a service principal (an identity for your script).

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, I think you can use **service principal** instead of your Microsoft account.

About create Azure service principal, we can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) via Azure portal to create it.

Then use PowerShell like this:

```
$subscriptionId="5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx"
$tenantid="1fcf418e-66ed-4c99-9449-d8e18bf8737a"
$clientid="1498b171-e1ca-451f-9d7a-8ef56a178b89" #appid
$password="7db814b1-xxxx-4654-xxxx-1d210cb546f9"
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientid, $userPassword
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential
```

In this way, we can use powershell to login it.

Comment: Is supplying the parameter client_Id mandatory? Its just the ADF which Iam trying to access not a specific app.

Comment: @Carol yes, not a specific app, logic one

Comment: @Carol Service principal works like system account, we can use it to login powershell in non-interactive way.

Comment: No it did not.. Still working on it. Beginning to feel 4c74356b41 is correct :/

Answer (score 1):

This is not posible (at least to my knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

Use an application password.

I've highlighted a couple things from the Microsoft documentation here, but the short version is that an app password is basically your personal back door to bypass MFA.  Note that for that reason an organization can restrict users from being able to create app passwords.

> An app password is a long, randomly generated password that you provide only once instead of your regular password when signing in to an app or device that doesn't support two-step verification.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords

> Certain non-browser apps, such as Outlook 2010, doesn't support two-step verification. This lack of support means that if you're using two-step verification, the app won't work. To get around this problem, you can create an auto-generated password to use with each non-browser app, separate from your normal password.
>
> You're given an app password during your initial two-step verification registration. If you need more than that one password, you can create additional passwords, based on how you use two-step verification
>
> Use one app password per device, not per app. For example, create a single password for all the apps on your laptop, and then another single password for all the apps on your desktop.
>
> There's a limit of 40 passwords per user. If you try to create one after that limit, you'll be prompted to delete an existing password before being allowed to create the new one.